# JAVA: Setting member data at creation, without using constructor

Tags: java

I'm working with som generated classes which I need to set the member data of at creation. The generated classes only have a default constructor, and no setters for the member data. It doesn't make sence to modify the classes, as the modification will be overwritten, when I regenerate the classes again (It's a shared project, so somebady else might also overwrite the generated classes).

Is it possible to do something like this.

Example:

```
public class A{
    private int value;
}

public class B{
    private A a;
    public void initA()
    {
        a = new A(){
            value = 9;
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve, and why overriding the argumentless constructor is impossible.

Comment: Also, if you want them to be unable to "overwrite" your constructor, declare `value` as `final` (you cannot change it anyway) - and if someone deletes your constructor - he'll get a compile time error and understand he did something wrong

Comment: **is it possible to do something like this.**
No You can't access a *private* field of class A in in method of class B.

Comment: If the fields are private, with no initialization and no setters, that sounds like the generated class is useless. I suggest you fix the generator.

Comment: You could use Reflections or modify the attribute to protected if you don't want to add getters and setters. But I sounds like you should proof your design

Comment: That is the point of OOP, that you usually make class fields private, so anyone couldn't change it. So answer is no, you can't change private field in another class(without constructor or setter).

Comment: You can use reflections, but it would be better if the code generation were fixed to produce sane code.  There is no point have private fields which cannot be set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this will allow you to set the value of the private field `A.value`:

```
class A {
    private int value;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Value of my private field: " + value;
    }
}

class MutableA {
    public A a;
    private Field value;

    public MutableA(A a) {
        this.a = a;
        try {
            this.value = A.class.getDeclaredField("value");
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        this.value.setAccessible(true);
    }

    void setValue(int value) {
        try {
            this.value.set(a, value);
        } catch (SecurityException | IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        System.out.println("before mutation:" + a);

        MutableA mutableA = new MutableA(a);
        mutableA.setValue(1);
        System.out.println("before mutation: " + a);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
before mutation: Value of my private field: 0
before mutation: Value of my private field: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only have no argument constructors you will have to use setters to set private members.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class A{
    private int value;
   static{
       value=10;
  }
}

public class B{
    private A a;
    public void initA()
    {
        a = new A();
    }
}
```

Comment: here we assign member variable at the time of creation without using constructor

Comment: The OP doesn't want to modify the class A. IF he/she was allowed to do that, then we could have had a member fucntion to do that

Comment: And even if he would that solution doesn't even compile. You're assiging and INSTANCE attribute in a STATIC init block. That means your attribute `value` doesn't even exist at the time you want to assign it.

Comment: private variable we can't access in base class so there no way to i thought to access that in derived class